# Не стартует MySQL в CentOS

Tags: mysql, битрикс, centos, mariadb

Обновил MySql.

Запускаю демон командой:

```
systemctl start mysql
```

Но мне пишет ошибку:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Хорошо, дальше следую указаниям и прописываю `systemctl status mysql.service`

```
* mysql.service - LSB: start and stop MariaDB
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: disabled)                                                                                                        
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-06-24 14:33:43 UTC; 2min 22s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)                                                                                                                                        
  Process: 8297 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 24 14:33:42 server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MariaDB...                                                                                                      
Jun 24 14:33:42 server mysql[8297]: Starting MariaDB.190624 14:33:42 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.                                                     
Jun 24 14:33:42 server mysql[8297]: 190624 14:33:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql                                                       
Jun 24 14:33:43 server mysql[8297]: /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql: line 264: kill: (8330) - No such process                                                                            
Jun 24 14:33:43 server mysql[8297]: ERROR!                                                                                                                                      
Jun 24 14:33:43 server systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1                                                                                  
Jun 24 14:33:43 server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MariaDB.
Jun 24 14:33:43 server systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.                                                                                                     
Jun 24 14:33:43 server systemd[1]: mysql.service failed.
```

Дальше прописываю еще команду `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- Unit session-64025062.scope has finished starting up.                                                                                                                        
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- The start-up result is done.                                                                                                                                                 
Jun 24 14:38:01 server systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of v-19852.                                                                                                         
-- Subject: Unit user-500.slice has finished start-up                                                                                                                           
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                          
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                         
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- Unit user-500.slice has finished starting up.                                                                                                                                
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- The start-up result is done.                                                                                                                                                 
Jun 24 14:38:01 server systemd[1]: Started Session 64025063 of user v-19852.                                                                                                    
-- Subject: Unit session-64025063.scope has finished start-up                                                                                                                   
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                          
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                         
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- Unit session-64025063.scope has finished starting up.                                                                                                                        
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- The start-up result is done.                                                                                                                                                 
Jun 24 14:38:01 server CROND[8612]: (v-19852) CMD (/var/www/v-19852/data/www/mobi.kz/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php)                                            
Jun 24 14:38:01 server CROND[8613]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/mgr5/sbin/cron-ispmgr sbin/mgrctl -m ispmgr periodic >/dev/null 2>&1)                                                
Jun 24 14:38:01 server systemd[1]: Started Session 64025061 of user root.                                                                                                       
-- Subject: Unit session-64025061.scope has finished start-up                                                                                                                   
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                          
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                         
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- Unit session-64025061.scope has finished starting up.                                                                                                                        
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- The start-up result is done.                                                                                                                                                 
Jun 24 14:38:01 server CROND[8616]: (root) CMD (   /opt/php71/bin/php -c /usr/local/mgr5/addon/revisium_antivirus/php.ini /usr/local/mgr5/addon/revisium_antivirus/services/queu
Jun 24 14:38:01 server systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of v-19852.                                                                                                         
-- Subject: Unit user-500.slice has finished shutting down                                                                                                                      
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                          
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                                                         
--                                                                                                                                                                              
-- Unit user-500.slice has finished shutting down.
```

Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему? Особо не разбираюсь в этом,но хотелось бы!

Comment: */etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql: line 264: kill: (8330) - No such process* — разбирайтесь, что там передаётся программе kill

Comment: мне кажется остался pid файл от процесса 8330
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid с цифрой 8330 внутри, либо
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.lock
сотри их !